# How to self-sign OpenPGP key again with Seahorse after changing key preferences?

Tags: gnupg, seahorse

I changed my preferences in `~/gnupg/gpg.conf`:

```
personal-cipher-preferences CAMELLIA256 AES256 TWOFISH CAMELLIA192 AES192 CAMELLIA128 AES
personal-digest-preferences SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 RIPEMD160
personal-compress-preferences BZIP2 ZLIB ZIP
```

And now I want to sign my OpenPGP key again. But seahorse tells me only:

> This key was already signed by ...

How can I re-sign my key with my new preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform advanced operations not possible with Seahorse, drop to the GnuPG command line.

1. Open edit key menu

   ```
   gpg --edit-key [key-id]
   ```
2. Select user ID to edit (repeat for all if necessary)

   ```
   list
   ```

   Each of the user IDs is prefixed with a number. If you want to edit the first UID, respectively type `1` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Delete the self-signature.

   ```
   delsig
   ```

   An assistant will guide you through all incoming signatures.

   Repeat steps 3 and 4 for all user IDs as necessary.
4. Save and exit the edit key menu.

   ```
   save
   ```
5. Recreate self-signature, either using the GnuPG command line (`gpg --edit-key [key-id]`, `sign`, `save`) or Seahorse.